# Gh Pages deploy Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

Im trying to deploy my react app on Gh pages but I keep getting this error: Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.

Anyone that can help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BJDq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are returning a 404 error along with this error message. If that is the case, your browser cannot find the manifest because of a MIME type issue.

In Chrome DevTools > Network > Headers > Content-Type, the content-type of the manifest must match the actual manifest file extension (`.json` or `.webmanifest`).

**Solution:**

Declare the `manifest` file type in `web.config`:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Hi! beginner here. Just checked, my content type is Text/HMTL. Where do I find web.config? It's not a file in my project (using create-react-app), or do I make it myself?